Is "Dogs walking slowly drives me crazy" grammatically correct?
Consulted several entities (some of them even assumed to be animated) but failed to reach an agreement. Some say it is not valid English and drives should be drive, others hold it should be Dogs' walking (with an apostrophe), but some believe Dogs walking slowly drives me crazy is fine.

I think the apostrophe version is the correct one— "Dogs' walking slowly drives me crazy." The drive version would suggest that it's the dogs that drive you crazy and not their "walking slowly." You could benefit more from reading about fused participle, which is what the apostrophe-less version is.

People bickering over that grammatical issue drive(s) me crazy.

There's no clear-cut "rule" in this area. From the top answer to the linked question: We might be OK with “People dancing in the street are a nuisance”. But “People dancing in the street are against the law” is a bridge too far. Telling examples, those.

@FumbleFingers, thanks for the refs. I'll read those. Anyway I didn't view walking here as a gerund, rather as a participle.

@user405662 why would a possessive apostrophe work? Is the act of walking possessed by the dogs? Is "walking slowly" a noun phrase? In speech wouldn't "Dogs' walking slowly" be confused with either "…a dog's walking slowly…"? or "Dogs (slowly) walking slowly" as in slowly walking dogs.

@Mari-LouA What about this example? He cannot allow his son's going without food? Is the apostrophe wrong here too? Should it be son going without?

@user405662 What about, "He cannot allow his son(s) to go without food"? EDIT If the original sentence were: "Dogowners' dogs that walk slowly drive him crazy” the possessive apostrophe  would make sense.

@user504245: Well, if you think your walking is a participle, then I guess by definition you think the verb should be plural drive, not singular drives. But note that immediately before the two examples I copied into my previous comment, Tuffy (the top answerer on the linked Q) said We still have to accept that dancing is a participle qualifying people in “I see people dancing in the street”. Point being that choosing to call it a participle or a gerund is exactly equivalent to choosing the plural or singular verb form (but my choice there is "flexible").

• Dogs walking slowly drives me crazy is the ACC-ing construction (the POSS-ing variant, • Dogs' walking slowly drives me crazy, is rarefied though not ungrammatical ... but apply Orwell's Sixth and avoid) and is perfectly acceptable. Here, • Dogs walking slowly drive me crazy is also available; some would say this is the whiz-deleted form of • Dogs that are walking slowly drive me crazy , with relative clause reduction. However you analyse it, it's grammatical.

'People swearing makes me sad' highlights the swearing, while 'People swearing make me mad' focuses on the people using bad language.

From a grammatical point of view, the subject could be a gerund-participial clause or an NP, hence either verb-form would be possible. In other words, “Dogs walking slowly” can be a gerund-participial clause with an accusative subject (genitive subjects are also possible). Clause subjects take singular agreement. Alternatively, it can be a noun phrase with “dogs” as head and “walking slowly” as a gerund-participial post-head modifier. Noun phrases with plural head nouns take plural agreement.
